# Cannot connect from spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j to cloud hosted neo4j server

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I am using neo4j for a project and I have a google cloud instance of neo4j running. 
Using the bolt protocol I can connect with this instance through the neo4j browser.
In the project, it works to have a local connection running on my laptop, but when I use the same bolt connection uri as I use in the browser for my cloud instance I get this error:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Connection to the database terminated. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0.
```

Clearly, it has something to do with the encryption settings. But I haven't, after hours of searching the internet for a solution, came closer to it. Dependencies are managed in gradle and the spring boot version is 2.2.4.RELEASE:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

runtimeOnly('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-postgresql:1.2.1.RELEASE')
runtimeOnly('com.h2database:h2')

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j:4.0.0'
compile 'org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver'
```

application.properties looks like this

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://34.76.157.40:7687
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=******
```

I have tried to set back the version of neo4j, since we do not specifically need 4.0.0, but this does not work. There is no config class in my project, and this issue is not related to the annotations I believe since it works locally.

Anyone who encountered the same issue or might help?

Comment: Did you find the solution for it? Am facing the same.

Comment: As I remember correctly, we set the encryption to false. The error should be more specific about what the default encryption is. Also I advise you to get a neo4j server that has encryption enabled if it is to be used in a production environment and not as a university project. 
`org.neo4j.driver.config.encrypted=false`

Answer (score 0):

This cost me quite some time to figure out, for my own application. So here's what worked for me.

I'm using neo4j 4.3.0 on Aura and Spring Data neo4j 6.1.6

In that case you need to add neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter to your Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and then configure your driver settings in application.properties like this:

```
org.neo4j.driver.uri=neo4j+s://xxxxxx.databases.neo4j.io
org.neo4j.driver.authentication.username=neo4j
org.neo4j.driver.authentication.password=your_password
org.neo4j.driver.config.encrypted=true
```

[This](https://medium.com/neo4j/using-neo4j-aura-from-java-and-spring-boot-f1c1684894f8) article brought me to the solution. You'll also find information for older versions and different configurations there.